# every sigma algebra is a borel set prove it

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is this right?

Q: Find an infinite collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that contains $\mathbb{R}$, is closed under the
formation of countable unions, and is closed under the formation of countable intersections, but is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

A: $\{[-a,a]:a\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\}\cup\{(-a,a):a\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\}\cup\{0\}\cup\{\mathbb{R}\}$

?

Comment: Slight problem: $\cap_{n=1}^\infty (-1-1/n,1+1/n) = [-1,1]$ is not an element of $A$, though each $(-1-1/n,1+1/n)$ is.

Comment: Now it looks okay.

Comment: You have to add $\mathbb{R}$ itself to the family.

Comment: What about now? @DanielFischer

Comment: It looks fine, can you prove it?

Comment: It's okay. But you don't need the half-open intervals, I'd remove them.

Comment: @YotasTrejos, clearly it is not closed under complementation. But the closedness under the formation of countable unions, and is closedness under the formation of countable intersections need some work i guess